# correct use of reflection to get a Class method

Tags: android, reflection

I try to implement the recommendation made in item #11 of [issue 111316656](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111316656) that says:

> You should also be able to use reflection to get access to the FloatingActionButtonImpl backing the fab, and then call setImageMatrixScale(1) on that instance.

with the following code:

```
            FloatingActionButton fab;
            ...    
            Method method = null;
            try {
                method = fab.getClass().getMethod("setImageMatrixScale", null);
                method.invoke(fab, 1);
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

But the `NoSuchMethodException` is raised. What is the problem?

Comment: It should be `getMethod("setImageMatrixScale", Float.TYPE)`, I believe.

Comment: No, Mike. I still get the NoSuchMethodException

Comment: Which library and version are you using for the `FloatingActionButton`?

Comment: implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misread your code. You need to get that method from `FloatingActionButtonImpl`, not `FloatingActionButton`. It would be something like `FloatingActionButtonImpl.class.getDeclaredMethod("setImageMatrixScale", Float.TYPE)`, provided that method exists in 28.0.0, and that class isn't hidden, or something.

Comment: Compiler error:
error: cannot find symbol class FloatingActionButtonImpl

Comment: Yeah, I was afraid of that. Gimme a second.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185166/discussion-between-ema3272-and-mike-m).

Comment: Here, try this: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1jTTcm9xFNscNDuL-HtAViPbqUfoNzcdi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of Mike M. (see comments in the question), this is the JAVA version of the workaround included in the referenced issue:

```
            fab.show(new FloatingActionButton.OnVisibilityChangedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onShown(FloatingActionButton fab) {
                    try {
                        Field implField = FloatingActionButton.class.getDeclaredField("impl");
                        implField.setAccessible(true);
                        Object impl = implField.get(fab);
                        Class cls;
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                            cls = impl.getClass().getSuperclass();
                        } else {
                            cls = impl.getClass();
                        }
                        Method mthd = cls.getDeclaredMethod("setImageMatrixScale", Float.TYPE);
                        mthd.setAccessible(true);
                        mthd.invoke(impl, 1);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like here

```
BluetoothGatt localBluetoothGatt = gatt;
  java.lang.reflect.Method localMethod = localBluetoothGatt.getClass().getMethod("refresh", new Class[0]);
  if (localMethod != null) {
    boolean bool = ((Boolean) localMethod.invoke(localBluetoothGatt, new Object[0])).booleanValue();
    return bool;
  }
```